# Graphql array of objects in parameter

Tags: javascript, graphql

I need to send graphql an array of objects in the parameter but I am getting an internal error "Cannot convert object to primitive value". Im not sure if this is on my backend or in the query itself. I cant find an example online where there is an array of objects in the parameter. Here is the query:

```
{
  searchProfile(query:"", limit: 10, sortBy: [{name: "name", sortOrder: "asc"}]){
    items{
      id
      name
      email
    }
    context
  }
}
```

Im created a graphql wrapper for a rest api let me know if more information is needed like dataSource, or resolvers.
Schema:

```
searchProfile(
  query: String
  sortBy: [JSONObject]
  cursor: String
  limit: Int
  context: JSONObject
): CustomerPagination
```

DataSource:

```
async searchProfile(query, sortBy, cursor, limit, context) {
    return this.get('getProfile/search', {
      ...(query && { query }),
      ...(sortBy && { sortBy }),
     ...other data ommitted
    });
  }
```

Resolvers.js:

```
searchCustomer: async (_, { query, sortBy, cursor, limit, context }, { dataSources }) => {
      return dataSources.api.searchProfile(query, sortBy, cursor, limit, context);
    },
```

Everything works until I added the sortBy param in the gql query.

Comment: I updated the post

Comment: It was defined as `scalar JSONObject` I think that type is fine because it is used all throughout the schema. I still feel like the error is in the query sortyby param because it instantly gives me an error doesnt even wait a second to load. And it doesnt call the resolver function

Comment: @sp00m Maybe you are right, how do you define the custom input?

Comment: @sp00m I also dont get it because I use JSONObject in other query definition params for the context param

Comment: Hmm ok, I'm not familiar with that "type-less" approach. You could still try explicitly typing if you want, e.g. `input Sort { name: String! sortOrder: String! }` and `sortBy: [Sort!]`. That how I'd do at least. I guess `sortOrder` can be either `asc` or `desc`, so a good candidate for an `enum` ;)

Comment: It still gives me the same error. Is there another example online of this case with the similar types of params

Comment: Your issue may come from somewhere else then. Do you have a stacktrace with that error message? If yes, line numbers could help you spot the cause.

Comment: @sp00m The stack trace points to the node_modules file for data source rest api. So it may be in the data source. Im trying to think, in the sortBy param for searchProfile in dataSource.js is it converting it to another data type?

Comment: @sp00m I found out that the sortBy value in dataSource.js is this `[ [Object: null prototype] { columnName: 'email', sortOrder: 'asc' } ]`  I need to find out why it has the [Object: null pototype in it